# Using PrototypeJs or pure JS, how can I avoid a click event but trigger the original handlers later?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a Place Order button, that contains a click event that will run some tasks and place the order via ajax.

I would like to add another click event that will be triggered **before** the original event, and perform some actions and validations.

Depending on the outcome of it:

1. I would like to prevent the other events to be triggered
2. OR if success, just proceed and call the other click listeners.

However I'm struggling a lot to achieve that with PrototypeJS or pure JavaScript.

This would be a simple example, but of course I tried many different approaches, including overrigind Event.observe method, cloning the button, and so on.

Any idea is appreciated.

```js
var button = $('onestepcheckout-place-order-button')

//Original event
button.observe('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Order submitted')
})

// New event (I only have access to modify from here onwards)
button.observe('click', function(event) {

  if (confirm('Are you sure?') === false) {
    console.log('The order should not be submitted')
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    return false
  }

  // The other events should be triggered (order submitted)
  button.fire('click')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.js"></script>
<button id="onestepcheckout-place-order-button" type="button"><span>Place order</span></button>
```

Comment: You could use a capturing event handler instead.

Comment: "*I only have access to modify from here onwards*" - are you saying you cannot modify the code of the "original" event handler, and that you cannot run any code before the original event handler is attached?

Comment: "*I was able to do this with jquery, but i'm struggling to do with prototypejs.*" - please show us the working jquery code

Comment: @Bergi in jQuery I captured the original submitHandler events, removed them all, and just added them back if my event succeeds. See the source core here: https://github.com/r-martins/PagBank-WooCommerce/blob/8ceb57b77882125a8d8d088722b51c67bed1b2b1/public/js/creditcard.js#L209  (line 224)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, although prototype can store the events internally, we cannot have access to it like we can in jQuery.

My **solution was to clone the original button** and add an event to it and also to the form, using pure javascript.

This way I was able to inject a clone of the original button, but without it events attached, run my function and its validation, and trigger the original button `click()` event if the validation passes.

Here's what I did:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('onestepcheckout-place-order-button')
var form = document.getElementById('orderForm')


// some code will add one or more event listeners to the original button
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Button clicked will submit form via ajax')
  //ajax (the order may be placed via ajax. replace the webhook.site url with yours if you want to see it in action there)
  new Ajax.Request('https://webhook.site/25fab621-3f15-4d9f-ad87-3a746113adf2', {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: '    '
    }
  })
}, false)

// clone the button
var newButton = button.cloneNode(true)

// replace old button for the new button (with no events attached)
button.parentNode.replaceChild(newButton, button)

// just a generic function to validate and prevent default
var validateAndPreventDefault = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault() // prevent the default behavior of the form/button

  if (confirm('Are you sure?') === false) {
    // add condition here
    // if some condition is not met, prevent the form from being submitted
    console.log('The order should not be submitted')

    return false
  }

  console.log('The order will bet submitted')
  button.click() // trigger the click event on the old button
  return true
  // The other events should be triggered (order submitted)
}

// add the event listener to the form and the button, preventing the default behavior in both cases
form.addEventListener('submit', validateAndPreventDefault, false)
newButton.addEventListener('click', validateAndPreventDefault, false)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js"></script>
<form id="orderForm" method="post" action="#">
  <!--    type button-->
  <button id="onestepcheckout-place-order-button" type="button"><span>Place order</span></button>

  <!--    type submit-->
  <button id="onestepcheckout-place-order-button-original" type="submit"><span>Submit button</span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a protection the browser puts in place, that prevents JS from artificially triggering click events that are not part of an original click event. For example, the browser will prevent you from triggering a click event on an element, if you trigger the event from a mouse move event.

In your scenario, because the `confirm()` method is triggered that interrupts the "flow" of the click event from one handler to the next.

Here's my suggestion, extract the order submitted handler into a separate method definition, so that method is called while passing the event to that method. The original click event listener can call that method, as well as the new one that has the "are you sure" `confirm()` call.

```
function submitorder(event){
   //... original submit order
}

$('onestepcheckout-place-order-button').observe('click',submitorder);
// OR 
$('onestepcheckout-place-order-button').observe('click',function(event){

    if (confirm('Are you sure?') === false) {
        console.log('The order should not be submitted')
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        return false
    }

    submitorder(event);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Actually the confirm() was just an idea of some validation that could fail and block the remaining events to happen.
The real scenario is that I need to encrypt the credit card data and perform some 3D authorization before the form is submitted OR the place order button is clicked.
If the 3D auth or the encryption fails, I need to stop the order of being placed (triggered by the first listener).
I cannot modify the other functions or listeners, because they may vary for each store.
I was able to do this with jquery, but i'm struggling to do with prototypejs.

Comment: @RicardoMartins gotcha, then most likely the problem is the difference between how PrototypeJS and jQuery handle triggering other events. I believe I have this correct, PrototypeJS will only attempt to directly trigger the event "closer to the metal", versus jQuery keeps an event map, and first tries to trigger the event directly, but then looks up the handler in the map, and triggers it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach a click event listener to the "Place Order" button, Then Inside the event listener, first perform some actions and validations using the `validateOrder()` function. If the validation somehow fails, prevent the default action of the click event, effectively preventing the order from being placed. and If the validation succeeds, we proceed with placing the order by calling the `placeOrder()` function, where you can put your AJAX call.

i think that will about do it.

//here is an example hope this will help

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       var placeOrderButton = document.getElementById('placeOrderButton');

// Add a click event listener to the "Place Order" button
placeOrderButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Perform some actions and validations
    var validationResult = validateOrder();

    // If the validation fails, prevent the default action of the click event
    if (!validationResult) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    // If the validation succeeds, proceed with placing the order
    placeOrder();
});

// now perform actions and validations
function validateOrder() {
    // Perform your validations here if true=succeed and viceversa
    var isValid = true;
    if (/* Your validation condition */) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}

// then place the order
function placeOrder() {
    // Perform your AJAX call here like:
    console.log('Order placed!');
}
```

});